# using of extra **kwargs in python: how to access the extra variables?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have a seemingly easy question which I can't find an answer to.
With a simple function such as the following:

```
def test_kwargs_1(a,**kwargs):
    print a
    print b
```

I was thinking that, if I passed:

```
kwargs = {'a':1,'b':2}
test_kwargs_1(**kwargs)
```

it would print:

```
1
2
```

as it would unpack "kwargs" and both a variable "a" and "b" would be available.
Instead i get:

```
1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
.
.
----> 3     print b
NameError: global name 'b' is not defined
```

I understand that "b" is a variable which may or may not exist, but I thought that the unpacking of kwargs would make the variable "b" available if explicitly defined in kwargs.
What am I not getting?
Thanks,
s

Comment: `b` is not declared in you function `test_kwargs_1`, as the error says. The way of accessing undefined `kwargs` in a function is threating it as a dictionary: `kwargs['b']`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star) and \* (star) do for Python parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is the explanation that I gave to myself but I find it a bit illogical. I thought that passing **kwargs, indipendently on if a variable is declared or not, would unpack what's in the kwargs dictionary and effectively do "a=1" and "b=2". It actually does "a=1", as print(a) works, while "b" remains a key of the dictionary and needs to be accessed. I understand how a function should give warnings (as "b" may be not passed), but it seems to me it is doing 2 different things according on if a argument is positional or not

Answer (score 6):

Using `**kwargs` in your function definition means that you can take any number of keyword arguments, and you will store them all in the dictionary called `kwargs`.  You can use `kwargs['b']` instead of b.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What surprises me is that with the "a" argument it actually does what I expected (i.e. the variable "a" is available, even if passed through the dictionary kwargs, while "b" is not). It seems to me it does two different things depending on if a variable is positional or not

Comment: It's the same as when it is positional.  With positional arguments, you can use `*args` which will not take *all* positional arguments; it will take only those that have not been accounted for.  It is the same thing with `**kwargs`.  `a` was already accounted for, but `b` wasn't so `kwargs` took it.